# .html() in jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, frontend

I am a total beginner with front-end development, and am trying to create a simple Tic Tac Toe game in HTML5. I have used a table to create the board. Here is the HTML code-

```
<section id="board">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="noTop noLeft">-</td>
            <td class="noTop">-</td>
            <td class="noTop noRight">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="noLeft">-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td class="noRight">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="noBottom noLeft">-</td>
            <td class="noBottom">-</td>
            <td class="noBottom noRight">-</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</section>
```

I am using jQuery for creating the logic. What I want is that whenever the user clicks on a square, an 'X' is displayed in that square. And here is what I have written for that-

```
$("td.noTop").click(function()  {
    $(this).html("X");
});
```

But the code doesn't seem to work at all, and no 'X appears on any square even if I click on them. How can I fix it?

Comment: can you show a demo or fiddle?

Comment: whether those elements are created dynamically

Comment: wrap the code in $(document).ready(function(){}); if the script is in head tag]

Comment: Do you, eah, *know* the `console`? Do you get another error there? Is your Javascript at all running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this function to work for first row only then use this code.

```
$('document').ready(function (){
    $("td.noTop").click(function()  {
        $(this).html("X");
    });
});`
```

if you want for all row and box you can use this code

```
$('document').ready(function (){
    $("#board td").click(function()  {
        $(this).html("X");
    });
});`
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure of [**DOM Ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function () {
    $("td.noTop").click(function()  {
        $(this).html("X");
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t58y1afk/)

Or if your HTML is generated dynamically, use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on("click", "td.noTop", function()  {
        $(this).html("X");
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t58y1afk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript that you have there will work but only if you click on the top line of the table

```
$("#board td").click(function()  {
    $(this).html("X");
});
```

try this

```
$("#board td").click(function()  {
    $(this).html("X");
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oL29tc9L/)